# True/false check across multiple google sheets with 2 criteria

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

So I've been trying to find a way to check multiple sheets on a column on the master sheet.

Previously the different sheets used a mixture of importrange and index/match to match town(each sheet is a different one)/number and pull a separate, matching columns number into said sheet.

=IF(B9>0,IFNA(INDEX(IMPORTRANGE("MAINSHEETLINK","Civils!$J$5:$J$500"), MATCH (B9,(IMPORTRANGE("MAINSHEETLINK","Civils!$I$5:$I$500"))*(IMPORTRANGE("MAINSHEETLINK","Civils!$D$5:$D$500")=$P$7), 0)),0),"0")

the $P$7 is the town name on the row it searches for.
The ifna just keeps it clean.

I can't figure out how I can use vlookup or query to search multiple sheets in this way. There's a separate Yes/No check on the secondary sheets that checks whether or not something was imported. I'd like a separate column on the main sheet to check across multiple sheets to true/false if the above check is Yes/No.

There's a possibility I have several nested if functions working through each sheet using the above index/match, but that seems prone to breaking, not to mention having to redo it once new sheets crop up.

Comment: share a copy of your sheets

Comment: Maybe your sheets have personal data. In that case do not share them and instead make a new sheet with a minimal example of the behavior that you'd like to achieve.